# Prove or disprove: if $\mu(E) > 0$, then $\int_E \int_E \frac{dx\,dy}{|x-y|} = \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Prove or disprove:  If $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then $\displaystyle\int_E \int_E \frac{dx\,dy}{|x-y|} = \infty$.

I believe this is true.  Since $\mu(E) > 0$, $E-E$ contains a neighborhood of 0, so $\int_{E-E} \frac{dx}{|x|} = \infty$, but I am having difficulty formally justifying the inequality
$$\int_E \int_E \frac{dx\,dy}{|x-y|} \geq \int_{E-E} \frac{dx}{|x|}$$

Intuitively, it seems obvious since the values $|x-y|$ range over $E-E$, but I would like to see the fully justified intermediate steps of reducing this double integral to a single integral.

Comment: How is E-E not empty?

Comment: $E-E$ as in the set of $x-y$ where $x,y \in E$

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt here $E-E= \{ x-y : x,y\in E    \}$

Comment: how about doing a change of variable $x^{\prime} = x - y$ and $y^{\prime} = x +y$.

Comment: So then we have $\int_{E-y}$ in the inner integral.  What next?

Comment: Do you know about points of density in the Lebesgue sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By choosing an appropriate subset, we may assume that $\mu(E) \in (0, \infty)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{E}\int_{E} \frac{dxdy}{\lvert x-y \rvert}
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathbf{1}_E(x)\mathbf{1}_E(y)}{\lvert x-y \rvert} \, dxdy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathbf{1}_E(x+y)\mathbf{1}_E(y)}{\lvert x \rvert} \, dxdy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\phi(x)}{\lvert x \rvert}\,dx
\end{align*}

where $\phi$ is defined by

$$\phi(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_E(x+y)\mathbf{1}_E(y) \, dy.$$

Notice that $\phi(0) = \mu(E) > 0$ and $\phi$ is continuous by $L^p$-continuity of translation. So there exist $c > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $\phi(x) \geq c$ on $[-\delta, \delta]$, and therefore

$$ \int_{E}\int_{E} \frac{dxdy}{\lvert x-y \rvert} \geq \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{c}{\lvert x \rvert}\,dx = \infty. $$

Answer (score 1):

Stronger result: For a.e $y\in E,$

$$\int_E \frac{1}{|x-y|}\, dx = \infty.$$

Proof: A.e. $y\in E$ is a point of density of $E$ in the Lebesgue sense. Fix such a $y.$ Note that

$$\frac{1}{|x-y| }= \int_{|x-y|}^\infty\frac{1}{t^2}\, dt,$$

which is a little devious. So the integral in question equals

$$\int_E \int_{|x-y|}^\infty\frac{1}{t^2}\, dt.$$

Switching the order of integration gives

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^2}\int_{E\cap(y-t,y+t)} dx \, dt=\int_0^\infty m({E\cap(y-t,y+t)})\, \frac{1}{t^2}\, dt.$$

Since $y$ is a point of density of $E,$ there exists $r >0$ such that $m({E\cap(y-t,y+t)})>t$ for $0<t<r.$ Thus the last integral is at least

$$\int_0^r  \frac{t}{t^2}\, dt = \infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $E$ $$\int_E \int_E \frac{\mathrm d x\mathrm dy}{|x-y|}\ge  \int_{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} \frac{\mathrm d x\mathrm dy}{|x-y|} =_{u= x-y, v = x} \int_\Omega \int_{\Omega-\Omega} \frac{\mathrm d u\mathrm d v}{|u|} = \mu(\Omega) \int_{\Omega-\Omega} \frac{\mathrm d u}{|u|}$$

Comment: I'm quite certain that $\mu(E) > 0$ does not imply $E^\circ \neq \emptyset$.  Additionally, I'm not certain why the inner integral is over $\Omega-\Omega$.